# How to append list which is inside a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with entries like `'0/RP0': ['NCS1K4-CNTLR']`. For each entry I have to add another string to the value. For example, appending `'OPERATIONAL'` results in `'0/RP0': ['NCS1K4-CNTLR','OPERATIONAL']`. I need to do this for the complete dictionary and have a list of values to append.

I have two dictionaries below,

```
new_dict =
{'0/RP0': ['NCS1K4-CNTLR'], '0/PM1': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC'], '0/PM0': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC'], '0/FT2': ['NCS1K4-FAN'], '0/FT0': ['NCS1K4-FAN'], '0/FT1': ['NCS1K4-FAN']}

new_dict_1=   
{'0/RP0': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM1': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM0': ['FAILED'], '0/FT2': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT0': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT1': ['OPERATIONAL']}
```

I want output like below,

```
{'0/RP0': ['NCS1K4-CNTLR','OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM1': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC','OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM0': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC','OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT2': ['NCS1K4-FAN','OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT0': ['NCS1K4-FAN','FAILED'], '0/FT1': ['NCS1K4-FAN','OPERATIONAL']}
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered; how is the order of appends determined?

Comment: Your list should be a dictionary using the same keys as your `new_dict`, otherwise there is no way to tie the list elements to the dictionary values.

Comment: if i am having the list as dict with same key values. can you tell me the code for that.    example:{'0/RP0': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM1': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM0': ['FAILED'], '0/FT2': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT0': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT1': ['OPERATIONAL']}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up your comment, your second dictionary can be merged with the first quite easily:

```
dict1 = {'0/RP0': ['NCS1K4-CNTLR'], '0/PM1': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC'], '0/PM0': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC'], '0/FT2': ['NCS1K4-FAN'], '0/FT0': ['NCS1K4-FAN'], '0/FT1': ['NCS1K4-FAN']}

dict2 = {'0/RP0': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM1': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM0': ['FAILED'], '0/FT2': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT0': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT1': ['OPERATIONAL']}

for k in dict1.keys():
    if k in dict2:
        dict1[k].append(dict2[k][0])

print(dict1)
```

Gives:

```
{'0/RP0': ['NCS1K4-CNTLR', 'OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM1': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC', 'OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM0': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC', 'FAILED'], '0/FT2': ['NCS1K4-FAN', 'OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT0': ['NCS1K4-FAN', 'OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT1': ['NCS1K4-FAN', 'OPERATIONAL']}
```

Note that `dict2[k][0]` is appended, otherwise we would append a list not a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two dictionaries, one with the lists and one with the strings to append, you can make use of the python dict.keys function.

```
dict_of_lists = {...}
dict_to_append ={...}
for key in dict_of_lists.keys():
    dict_of_lists[key].append(dict_of_keys[key])
```

If the second dict contains lists, you might want to use extent instead of append.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some use of `zip()` method but as it's been mentioned: dictionaries are unordered in Python, so there's probably something more in the code you'd have to change.

```
In [14]: my_dict = {'ak': ['av'], 'bk': ['bv']}

In [15]: my_list = ['a1v', 'b1v']

In [16]: for element in zip(my_dict, my_list):
    ...:     my_dict[element[0]].append(element[1])
    ...:     

In [17]: my_dict
Out[17]: {'ak': ['av', 'a1v'], 'bk': ['bv', 'b1v']}
```

Don't be misguided with the result, it could also be `{'ak': ['av', 'b1v'], 'bk': ['bv', 'a1v']}`

Most probably you'd need two dicts and zip them isntead with something like:

```
In [18]: my_dict = {'ak': ['av'], 'bk': ['bv']}

In [19]: my_dict_2 = {'ak': ['a1v'], 'bk': ['b2v']}

In [20]: for element in zip(my_dict, my_dict_2):
    ...:     my_dict[element[0]].append(my_dict_2[element[1]][0])
    ...:     

In [21]: my_dict
Out[21]: {'ak': ['av', 'a1v'], 'bk': ['bv', 'b2v']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehensions may be more efficient than loops. The below method also replaces checking for key existence via `if` statement with `dict.get` default value.

```
dict1 = {'0/RP0': ['NCS1K4-CNTLR'], '0/PM1': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC'], '0/PM0': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC'], '0/FT2': ['NCS1K4-FAN'], '0/FT0': ['NCS1K4-FAN'], '0/FT1': ['NCS1K4-FAN']}

dict2 = {'0/RP0': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM1': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/PM0': ['FAILED'], '0/FT2': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT0': ['OPERATIONAL'], '0/FT1': ['OPERATIONAL']}

dict1_new = {k: v + dict2.get(k, []) for k, v in dict1.items()}

# {'0/FT0': ['NCS1K4-FAN', 'OPERATIONAL'],
#  '0/FT1': ['NCS1K4-FAN', 'OPERATIONAL'],
#  '0/FT2': ['NCS1K4-FAN', 'OPERATIONAL'],
#  '0/PM0': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC', 'FAILED'],
#  '0/PM1': ['NCS1K4-2KW-AC', 'OPERATIONAL'],
#  '0/RP0': ['NCS1K4-CNTLR', 'OPERATIONAL']}
```